# How to set up jdk 8 on mac m1?

Tags: java, installation, java-8, environment

i have jdk 16 installed but due to certain reasons i want jdk8 now.

my jdk 16 is not installed on $JAVA_HOME

i have no documentation on how to install jdk8 since all documentation are for -bash, while my mac has -zsh and i also don't know how to set up environment variable and all(i am a complete beginner).

it would be really helpful if someone could guide me for installation

Comment: I have guided you to the standard question about JDKs for Apple M1.

Comment: 1) The bash installation instructions should work with zsh.  2) Environment variables are the same as for zsh. 3) There are tutorials on how to use a bash or zsh shell for complete beginners.